# How to Migrate Old Visual Studio Project to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, migration, sqlclr

**Goal:**
I try to open a visual studio project (c#) with CLR code for SQL Server from the Pluralsight [course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/sql-server-tsql/exercise-files).

**Issue:**
I get no error messages just warnings below after *One-way upgrade* on Visual Studio 2017.

> Your project is targeting .NET Framework 2.0 or 3.0. If your project
>   uses assemblies requiring a newer .NET Framework, your project will
>   fail to build. You can change the .NET Framework version by clicking
>   Properties on the project menu and then selecting a new version in the
>   '.NET Framework' dropdown box. (In Visual Basic, this is located on
>   the Compile tab by clicking the 'Advanced Compiler Options...'
>   button.)

- When I open a solution with single project inside I get message below

> The Project Needs to be migrated

or

> The Project Needs to be loaded

[image]

**Tried:**
I tried editing csproj files with newer/older version [numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History).
I tried different PCs with Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2015

**Idea**: Install Visual Studio 2010 as course was released in 2010 BUT I really do not want that.

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.NET?

Comment: the project is using c#

Comment: First, I think this is a warning, not an error. Second, if you go to the project Properties, then to the SQLCLR tab, you should see a drop-down for "Target Framework". Do you see it?

Comment: the project does not open it says 'Needs Migration'. Therefore, I cannot see it. just the message instead of a project

Answer (score 3):

When I got this issue, I tried reloading the project and when I did, it told me that I did not have an SDK installed and then it offered to install the SDK.  Once I had the SDK installed, the project loaded and I was able to work with the project.